# Using async/await calls an api in jest always get status 200

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I call an api in my `App.test.js` file to test API:

I have install `jest-fetch-mock`

Here is my devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.6.6",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
```

`App.test.js`:

```
describe('Test API', () => {

  it('ack', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/drivers?city=TaipeiWest&lng=121.514163&lat=25.049447');
    expect(response).toBeDefined();
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

I found that if I use useless api `https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/drivers?city=&lng=121.514163&lat=25.049447`.

or remove it

```
const response = await fetch('');
```

then type `npm run test`

I still get the status is 200

Here is the console.log

```
Response {
  type: 'default',
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: Headers { map: { 'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' } },
  url: '',
  _bodyInit: '',
  _bodyText: '' }
```

Why async/awiat is not working? I think that I will get status is 422.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thans in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always getting that response because you are not waiting for the promise of the request when using async/await. This is happening because you are not using async properly in your `describe` method.

Have a look [at this article](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html) specifically [no await in callbacks](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html#no-await-in-callbacks) and [Unit testing with async functions](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html#unit-testing-with-async-functions)

For your code to work correctly, add async to your `describe` inner arrow function like this:

```
describe('Test API', async () => {
    it('ack', async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/drivers?city=TaipeiWest&lng=121.514163&lat=25.049447');
        expect(response).toBeDefined();
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

If you still get the same response, add `await` to `it` (if the response is a promise there should be no problem):

```
await it('ack', async () => {
```

You can also have a look at [this issue in jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2235) and have a look at [this article](https://alligator.io/testing/asynchronous-testing-jest/) on how to handle async tests.

Comment: I use `await it('ack', async () => {` it is promise exactly though the api is empty still returns status is 200. Can't figure it out yet. Thanks for a lots of useful information, I will study it.